# Fatal error using AlamoFireImage to load a url of Arrays using the .af_setImage method in a CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, alamofireimage

I'm getting an Array of urls from my REST API and I want to use them to load images from the server using AlamofireImage .af_setImage method for my collection view cells. But I'm getting the following error message in the debug console:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCellIdentifiers.searchResultCell, for: indexPath) as! CreaTuCanastaCollectionViewCell

        let urlString = productPictures[indexPath.item]

        if let url = URL(string: productPictures[indexPath.item]) {
            cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)
        }

     return cell
   }
}
```

The strange thing is that the debug console throws this:

[image: Console output]

Which means the values are there, yet it keeps throwing me the 
fatal error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any ideas?

### Edit

I tried using SDImage instead of AlamoFireImage

```
 if let url = URL(string: productPictures[indexPath.item]) {

            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url)
        }
```

And I get the same results

### Edit

I tried a different approach this time I put this code inside the cellForItemAt method:

```
Alamofire.request(urlArray).responseImage { response in
            debugPrint(response)

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)

            if let image = response.result.value {

                    cell.imageView.image = image
            }
```

Which gives me this response in the debugging console:

```
SUCCESS
<UIImage: 0x620000283fc0>, {300, 300}
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x62800002cb80> { URL: https://i1.wp.com/pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1 } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=63115200";
"Content-Length" = 24757;
"Content-Type" = "image/jpeg";
Date = "Thu, 01 Dec 2016 06:06:41 GMT";
Etag = "\"629f656831de2958\"";
Expires = "Sat, 01 Dec 2018 18:00:39 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Thu, 01 Dec 2016 06:00:39 GMT";
Link = "<https://pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg>; rel=\"canonical\"";
Server = nginx;
Vary = Accept;
"x-bytes-saved" = 2467;
"x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
"x-nc" = "HIT bur 66";
} }
[Data]: 24757 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: <UIImage: 0x6280002830c0>, {300, 300}
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 502265200.175, "Initial     Response Time": 502265200.756, "Request Completed Time": 502265200.813, "Serialization Completed Time": 502265200.821, "Latency": 0.581 secs, "Request Duration": 0.638 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.008 secs, "Total Duration": 0.645 secs }
Optional(https://i1.wp.com/pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1)
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x62800002cb80> { URL: https://i1.wp.com/pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1 } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=63115200";
"Content-Length" = 24757;
"Content-Type" = "image/jpeg";
Date = "Thu, 01 Dec 2016 06:06:41 GMT";
Etag = "\"629f656831de2958\"";
Expires = "Sat, 01 Dec 2018 18:00:39 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Thu, 01 Dec 2016 06:00:39 GMT";
Link = "<https://pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg>; rel=\"canonical\"";
Server = nginx;
Vary = Accept;
"x-bytes-saved" = 2467;
"x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
"x-nc" = "HIT bur 66";
} })
SUCCESS
<UIImage: 0x6280002830c0>, {300, 300}
2016-12-01 00:06:41.110589 pixan[9961:2940658] []
```

But I'm still getting the same mistake.

Comment: You should check the `cell` object for being nil. Because you are using `dequeueReusableCell` function but if there is no cell has been created for reusing then it'll return nil.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlstr = ""   
if let urlString = productPictures[indexPath.item] as? String
{
 urlstr = urlString
}
cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: urlstr!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "imgPlaceHolder"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in})
```

Comment: Tried your solution brother but it gets the same reply.

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thanks anyway!

Comment: view.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:"https://i1.wp.com/pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "imgPlaceHolder"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in}


its working when i retry with your Static url..

https://postimg.org/image/yk81a62wx/

Comment: please print every UrlString and NSURL with index number before set "sd_setImageWithURL" . so, that it will make clear you which one is nil at array index

Comment: This is a very good clue! I hadn't thought of that will try it, thanks!

Comment: and one more thing encode the url before set to  "sd_setImageWithURL" 
this one will be also an reason of nil .

var stringUrl = "https://..."

let URL = NSURL(string: stringUrl.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!

Comment: I tried what you said my friend and I got this:

Item1: https://i2.wp.com/pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-familia.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1
Item2: https://i1.wp.com/pixan.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/canasta-pareja.jpg?fit=600%2C600&ssl=1
..........

What is interesting though is that after Item53: the array repeats itself starting again at Item1 it repeats for about 6 times

Also I tried the same you did uploading just a single picture from the static url in an imageview and it worked, the problem is the collection view. 

EDIT Will try the encoding.

Comment: I tried encoding the string but it doesn't work either, I'm completely puzzled on what is wrong. Thanks for all your help and advices.